# How to change null value from default-reply-timeout property in gateway element for Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a gateway defined like this:

```
 <int:gateway 
    service-interface="com.charter.egateway.integration.accountbase.AccountBaseSearchServiceInterface"  
    default-reply-timeout="13000" >
    <int:method name="search" request-channel="accountBaseRequestChannel" reply-channel="accountBaseResponseChannel" />
        </int:gateway>
```

When it timeouts after 13s, my code below receives a 'null' - but I'm using 'null' for 'null responses', i.e, responses without content:

```
@Secured(SecurityRoles.ROLE_READ)
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(
        value = "This service works like a single entry to execute searches on Salesforce", 
        notes = "Returns a list of accounts."
)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = AccountSearchResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid request.", response = ErrorResponse.class, responseContainer="List"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error.", response = ErrorResponse.class, responseContainer="List"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "No content.", response = AccountSearchResponse.class)
})
public ResponseEntity<?> search(@Valid AccountSearchRequest objectSearch) {

    logger.debug("Returning request: {}.", objectSearch.toString());
    ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>response = RequestMessageValidator.validate(objectSearch);
    if (null != response) {
        logger.debug("Returning ErrorResponse: {}.", response.toString());
        return response;
    }
    Message<AccountSearchRequest> requestMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(objectSearch).setCorrelationId(transaction.getTransactionId()).build();
    EndAccountSearchResponse searchResponse = (EndAccountSearchResponse) service.search(requestMsg);



    if(searchResponse==null){
        logger.debug("Returning no content.");
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }


    logger.debug("Returning Response: {}.", searchResponse.toString());
    return  ResponseEntity.ok(searchResponse);
}
```

How can I differentiate outcome from timeout, which is null from 'no content' (searchResponse == null)?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can't "return null". `null` is an invalid message payload; when a component in an integration flow returns null; the flow stops; nothing is sent back to the gateway. The gateway will always time out (and return null) in this case.

You should either return a special value indicating no result, or throw an exception (and catch it).